# Why cannot I declare class outside of class in Vala (error: redefinition of struct)?

Tags: vala

The example below, `test4.vala`, compiles and runs:

```
//// compile with: valac test4.vala

//~ public class TestClass : GLib.Object { // error: redefinition of ‘struct _TestClass’
  //~ public int x = 0;
  //~ public int y = 0;
  //~ public int z = 0;
//~ }

public Test App;

public class Test : GLib.Object {

  public class TestClass : GLib.Object {  //current
    public int x = 0;                     //current
    public int y = 0;                     //current
    public int z = 0;                     //current
  }                                       //current

  public TestClass mytc;
  public void SetVars() {
    mytc = new TestClass();
    stdout.printf("SetVars called, %p\n", mytc);
  }

  public Test(string[] args){
    stdout.printf("Test() ctor: ok\n");
    stdout.flush();
  }

  public static int main (string[] args) {
    App = new Test(args);
    App.SetVars();
    stdout.printf("main called\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

However, if I comment the lines marked "current", and uncomment the commented code, I get this error:

```
$ valac test4.vala && ./test4 
/tmp/test4.vala.c:64:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _TestClass’
 struct _TestClass {
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test4.vala.c:20:16: note: originally defined here
 typedef struct _TestClass TestClass;
                ^~~~~~~~~~
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I still trying to grok Vala, but this kinda leaves me puzzled - why cannot I compile an additional class outside the one carrying `main` on a same level with it - but I have to instead "include" this other class in the main app class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with how GObject works and its naming conventions.  The GObject manual has [more details](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gtype-instantiable-classed.html), so I'm not going to go into much depth here…

When you create an object, let's call it `Foo`, in Vala, in the generated C two structs will be created: `Foo` and `FooClass`.  The former is what people will mostly use in the API and represents an instance of `Foo`, whereas the latter is used to hold information about the `Foo` class itself; virtual function pointers are the big thing.

So, with your above code, the generated code will contain `Test` and `TestClass` for the outer class, and `TestTestClass` and `TestTestClassClass` for the inner class.  Once you uncomment the rest of the code, it will try to generate `TestClass` and `TestClassClass`, the former of which will conflict with the `*Class` struct for the outer class that already existed.

You could reproduce the issue a bit more easily with just:

```
public class Test : GLib.Object { }
public class TestClass : GLib.Object { }
```

Basically, don't call a class `*Class`.